# How to suppress a popup window while using certreq to request a certificate from an enterprise CA?

Tags: powershell, certificate, popupwindow, ca, certreq

I am trying to request a certificate from a machine that is in the same domain as our enterprise CA server. Everything is working fine but I'm one step away from making my script have zero user interaction.

I basically modified the following script to contain no parameters and removed the SAN options:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Request-Certificate/1.5.0

After the following command to create a new request from an .inf file, I get a popup window:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "certreq -new `"$inf`" `"$req`""
```

`Machine context template conflicts with user context.`

When I click OK, everything works fine. A new request gets created and rest of the script works fine. But I can't find a way to click "OK" programmatically.

certreq tool does have the `-q` (to suppress interactive prompts) and `-f` (to force/bypass things) but none of those work.

`certreq -new -q $inf $req` OR using both `-q` and `-f` results in:

```
Active Directory Enrollment Policy
  {<GUID>}
  ldap:
Machine context template conflicts with user context.
Certificate Request Processor: The specified role was not configured for the application 0x8004e00c (-2147164148 CONTEXT_E_ROLENOTFOUND)
```

I am pretty much stuck here. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the template is of kind `Computer` and not `User`. That means the request should be created in the context of the computer account. This means you must run the script as `SYSTEM`, `Administrator` or any other account allowed to identify as the Computer.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question should be changing param in Request-Certificate.ps1.
Take a look at inf file for generating request and check *MachineKeySet* param.
Default is false and prompt:

```
Machine context template conflicts with user context.
```

appers when template is of kind Machine.
When you switch it to true ale use User template there is opposite prompt:

```
User context template conflicts with machine context.
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who come here to suppress the prompt to select a CA, add `-config <FQDN_OF_CA>\<LOGICAL_NAME_OF_CA>` to your `CertReq` command.